# How can i pass the parameter using the display tag?

Tags: tags, struts, query-string, displaytag, querystringparameter

I am using the display tag.In my display:column i need the href link on my record and if click the link of the count it go to my action page of struts at the same time i need 'which instance type' and 'rating element id'.So please give me the suggestion to pass the value as a query string..Currently am using struts version 1.2.9
My sample code is,

<%@include file="/jsp/include/displaytag.jsp"%>

```
<c:if test="${(asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType != null && asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType != 'Sum')}">
    <display:column property="instanceTypeDescription" title="Instance Type" sortable="false"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${(asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType != null && asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType == 'Sum')}">
    <display:column property="instanceType" title="Instance Type" sortable="false" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center"/>
</c:if>

<display:column property="firstWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFirstWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" >
    <a href="weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportPost.do?method=WeeklyDlvyInstExcelReport&instanceType=${asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType}&ratingElementId=${asnAccuracyListUID.ratingElementId}">${asnAccuracyListUID.firstWeekOfCount}</a>  
</display:column>
<display:column property="secondWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracySecondWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"  />
<display:column property="thirdWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyThirdWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"  />
<display:column property="fourthWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFourthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" />
<display:column property="fifthWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFifthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" />
<display:column property="sixthWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracySixthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"/>
```

Comment: You are using Struts2... try using <s:property> tags instead of JSTL tags, and <s:a> with <s:url> and <s:param> for a simpler code...

Comment: Ah ok... by the way, your URL seems incorrect, you are using TWO times the '?' mark for parameters...

Comment: @Swift sorry i mistyped that..

Comment: What does it prints in the <a> href attribute ?

Comment: i typed some name 'details'. but i want to display the column value using the property="firstWeekOfCount"

Answer (score 0):

Remove `property="firstWeekOfCount"` from `<display:column property="firstWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFirstWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" >`

Comment: if i remove the property it doesn't show anything. Why u said to remove that property. Are you trying to say anything for a specific reason ? can you explain me in detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i got this for my question that is..

```
<display:table name="${weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportForm.asnAccuracyListQO}" uid="asnAccuracyListUID" sort="list" defaultsort="1" 
                                        requestURI="/weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportPre.do?method=httpGet" excludedParams="method"
                                        decorator="com.ford.mpl.superg.decorator.WeeklyDeliveryInstancesTypeTableDecorator" keepStatus="true">
                                        <%@include file="/jsp/include/displaytag.jsp"%>
                                        <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.firstWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracyFirstWeekOfCount"/>
                                        <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.secondWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracySecondWeekOfCount"/>
                                        <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.thirdWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracyThirdWeekOfCount"/>
                                        <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.fourthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracyFourthWeekOfCount"/>
                                        <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.fifthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracyFifthWeekOfCount"/>
                                        <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.sixthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracySixthWeekOfCount"/>

                                        <c:if test="${(asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType != null && asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType != 'Sum')}">
                                            <display:column property="instanceTypeDescription" title="Instance Type" sortable="false"/>
                                        </c:if>
                                        <c:if test="${(asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType != null && asnAccuracyListUID.instanceType == 'Sum')}">
                                            <display:column property="instanceType" title="Instance Type" sortable="false" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center"/>
                                        </c:if>

                                        <display:column property="firstWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFirstWeekOfCount}" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportPost.do?method=WeeklyDlvyInstExcelReport" paramProperty="instanceType" paramId="instanceTypeForJSP" sortable="false" />                          
       <display:column property="secondWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracySecondWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"  />
                                        <display:column property="thirdWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyThirdWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"  />
                                        <display:column property="fourthWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFourthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" />
                                        <display:column property="fifthWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFifthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" />
                                        <display:column property="sixthWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracySixthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"/>
                                    </display:table>
```